# Messenger PHP chatbot receives more JSONs

Tags: php, json, chatbot

my PHP chatbot receives multiple JSONs with php://input. It gets input message (that's correct), but then it receives JSON with message sent by bot (response), delivery confirmation and read confirmation.

How can I keep only that first JSON?

I need it because it then has problem when I send an attachment to my bot, it processes wrong JSON and I cannot get URL from it.

I have this code for handling input:

```
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

file_put_contents('idkResponse.txt', file_get_contents('php://input') . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

And I'm getting all these JSONs

```
{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"XXXXX","time":1496729805870,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"XXXXX"},"recipient":{"id":"XXXXX"},"timestamp":1496729805429,"message":{"mid":"mid.$XXXXX","seq":1459814,"text":"Hey"}}]}]}

{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"XXXXX","time":1496729806679,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"XXXXX"},"recipient":{"id":"XXXXX"},"timestamp":1496729806556,"message":{"is_echo":true,"app_id":XXXXX,"mid":"mid.$XXXXX","seq":1459815,"text":"Wut?"}}]}]}

{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"XXXXX","time":1496729806873,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"XXXXX"},"recipient":{"id":"XXXXX"},"timestamp":1496729806873,"delivery":{"mids":["mid.$XXXXX"],"watermark":XXXXX,"seq":0}}]}]}

{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"XXXXX","time":1496729808233,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"XXXXX"},"recipient":{"id":"XXXXX"},"timestamp":1496729808232,"read":{"watermark":XXXXX,"seq":0}}]}]}
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried getting only message and ID of the sender? I did it while making a complete chatbot here: https://chatbotslife.com/how-to-build-facebook-messenger-chatbot-in-php-with-structured-messages-59fb4e839f3c

Comment: Yes, when I send only text message, it works ok. But when I send an attachment, it then stores wrong JSON in $input and tries to find attachment URL in wrong JSON - I get an error "PHP Notice:  Undefined index: message in..."

Comment: I've also send attachments in the article try it out if it can solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, it's working now! I firstly set up my webhook by another tutorial and there was said to check all webhook events (message, message read, message delivery...), so I unchecked all except message and now it's ok :)